# How to manipulate a "zoo" object for Forecasting?

Tags: r, zoo

I have daily data for sales. There is a pattern to have higher sales on Saturday and Sunday. Initially I worked with tseries library and tried to create forecasts with auto.arima. Later I read that it's better to use a zoo object for daily data. I did so. I also followed Gabor's steps from this link https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-February/269069.html , and I got rid off Feb 29th.

My question is how to manipulate the zoo object and create forecasts? 
Can I apply a specific model from "forecast" package or do I have to check auto correlation,trend,seasonality separately on the "zoo" object. 
I've seen some people converting zoo to ts or xts. When I convert it to a ts I loose my time index which is the Date. 
I apologize for not providing my dataset but I lost power before and I can only see my commands from the Rapp.history. 
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you